# How to use external clienttemplate( with nested template) in the Kendo UI grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My client template begin to be very big, and I would love to be able to put it inside a `<script>`

My 2 problems are:

- How can I set an external script to be my clientTemplate?
- How can I nested another script/template into my main template.

Here is what I have right now that I want to change:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Car>()
              .Name("testGrid)
              .BindTo(Model.CarList)
              .Columns(columns =>
              {

                  columns.Bound(a => a.CarInitialAndNumber)
                      .Width(150)
                      .IncludeInMenu(false)
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#=CarInitialAndNumber#" })

                      .ClientTemplate(
                          "#=CarInitialAndNumber# <span role=\"menuitem\" class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus jqtooltip k-header-column-menu' " +
                          "title='<table class=\"uitooltip\">" +
                          "<tr><td><span>" + Resources.CarGrid_Column_CCO + ":</span></td><td>#=CCO#</td><td><span>" + Resources.CarGrid_Column_Length + ":</span></td><td>#=Length#</td></tr>" +
                          "<tr><td><span>" + Resources.CarGrid_Column_NetWeight + ":</span></td><td>#=NetWeight#</td></tr>" +
                          "<tr><td><span>" + Resources.CarGrid_Column_Pool + ":</span></td><td>#=Pool#</td><td><span>" + Resources.CarGrid_Column_Shipper + ":</span></td><td>#=Shipper#</td></tr>" +
                          "<tr><td><span>" + Resources.CarGrid_Column_Origin + ":</span></td><td colspan=\"3\">#=OriginFacility#</td></tr></table>'" +
                          " style='float:right;line-height:10px;margin-top:4px'></span>"
                      )
                      .Title(Resources.CarGrid_Column_CarInitialNumber);


             })
             .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                         .Ajax()
                         .Read(read => read.Action("GetCars", "controller").Data("getCriteria"))
                  )
             .Events(o => o.DataBound("onCarDatabound"))
```

But I would like to put it in something like that( 2 differents template. 1 for the container, and the other for the tooltip.):

```
<script id="detail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #=CarInitialAndNumber#
    <span role="menuitem" class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus jqtooltip k-header-column-menu'
          title="#=UseToolTipTemplate#"
          style="float:right;line-height:10px;margin-top:4px">
    </span>
</script>

<script id="detailtooltip-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<table class="uitooltip">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>@(Resources.CarGrid_Column_CCO) :</span>
        </td>
        <td>#=CCO#</td>
        <td>
            <span>@(Resources.CarGrid_Column_Length) :</span>
        </td>
        <td>#=Length#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>@(Resources.CarGrid_Column_NetWeight) :</span>
        </td>
        <td>#=NetWeight#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>@(Resources.CarGrid_Column_Pool) :</span>
        </td>
        <td>#=Pool#</td>
        <td>
            <span>@(Resources.CarGrid_Column_Shipper) :</span>
        </td>
        <td>#=Shipper#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>@(Resources.CarGrid_Column_Origin) :</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">#=Origin#</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>
```

I just don't know how can I set the value of this specific clientTemplate to the one inside my script..

Comment: Your trying to set up 1 grid, with 1 sub grid? or 2 sub grids?

Comment: No I only want 1 grid, with a custom column clientTemplate. no sub grid

Comment: What do you want to do with the template

Comment: Well if you look at the example, you will see that I want to show custom information in the template, like a value, and a tooltip containing a lot of value